# bash vs sh cannot use unamed stream diff <(doSomething) <(doSomethingElse)

Tags: diff, sh

I want to compare two stream.  I wrote the following code in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash    
diff <({
#premier commentaire
cat test_similar1
}) <({
#second commentaire
cat test_similar2
})
```

It worked.  Instead, the following code in sh

```
#!/bin/sh    
diff <({
#premier commentaire
cat test_similar1
}) <({
#second commentaire
cat test_similar2
})
```

does not : it gave the following error.

```
test.sh: 2: test.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

How can I use sh instead of bash on my RHEL server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sh` does not support the `<(command)` "process substitution" syntax. You'll need to use some temporary files, or named pipes, to hold command output. Of course, proper tempfile management is *hard*.

One thing: if you are just using `cat` of single files inside the process substitutions, there's no need for the substitutions. Just give `diff` the filenames.